# Jade conditional output different/conditional form attributes with same form body

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a small issue with conditional rendering of some part of html in jade, doing my best not to duplicate code. I have the following jade bit

```
if(loggedIn && !search)
   form(action="/list/mine")
else if(search)
   form(action="/list/search", method="POST")
else
   form(action="/list/all")

   input(type="hidden" value=parseInt(next) name="skip" )
   input(type="submit" value="Next" class="pure-button pure-button-primary")
```

I want the above `if` to produce

```
form(action="/list/mine")
   input(type="hidden" value=parseInt(next) name="skip" )
   input(type="submit" value="Next" class="pure-button pure-button-primary")
```

Similarly `else if`, and `else` clauses (with different form values).

At the moment body of the form is output-ed only when `else` is valid, it makes sense why it does. For some reason, my mind give up on me.

How can I achieve conditional printing of form body with different form attributes without having to duplicate the form body? Pleas show a valid jade sample code if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have made use of JavaScript inside jade with two variables for `action` and `method`. Not sure how good this solution is, feel free to post an answer if you have a better solution for this question.

```
- var action = "";
- var method = "";
 if(loggedIn && !search)
   - action = "/vehicle/secure/api/list/mine";
   - method = "GET";
 else if(search)
   - action = "/vehicle/api/search";
   - method = "POST";
 else
   - action = "/vehicle/api/list";
   - method = "GET";
 form(action=action, method=method)
   input(type="hidden" name="skip" value=parseInt(next))
   input(type="submit", value="Previous" class="pure-button pure-button-p
```

Comment: This helped me avoid having to duplicate my entire code just because I wanted to check if a user is admin level 1 or admin level 2.